# Tensorflow Objct detection API error: ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v2 is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am using the TF Object detection API. I am using TF2.4.1, python 3.6, and want to train the mobilenet_v2

I downloaded the official `SSD MobileNet v2 320x320` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)
When running the training from

```
/tensorflow/model/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py
```

I get the follownig error:

> ... File
> "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AIOD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
> line 251, in _check_feature_extractor_exists
> 'Tensorflow'.format(feature_extractor_type))

> ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v2 is not supported. See `model_builder.py`
> for features extractors compatible with different versions of
> Tensorflow

in my pipeline.config file the fteature extractor is unchanged as:

```
feature_extractor {
  type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
...
      }
```

in the `... /model_builder.py` I find that the `SSD_FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_MAP`, which is checked in this case, includes the `ssd_mobilenet_v2` (Line 185 in model_builder).

Before, I had a problem, that the `pipeline.config` file could not be found even so I gave the exact location. Copying the `pipeline.config` file to the `tensorflow/models/own_model_Dir` made that error dissapear. So maybe, I have to put the model I downloaded into a specfic folder?

**Questions**

---

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

**Do you know where I have to place the model? Do I also have to place it into the `tensorflow/models` dir?**

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that `SSD_FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_MAP` is under `if tf_version.is_tf1():`
as I run with TF2.4.1 I am not tf1.

To avoid this either use TF<2 (even though it says in the name `model_main_tf2.py`) or

you chose as feature extractor in your pipeline.config
e.g., `ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras`. I still have to figure out which is fitting, but that would be a soultion as this extractor is in `SSD_KERAS_FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_MAP` which is under `if tf_version.is_tf2():`

... Of ourse I ran into toher problems, but that is not for this thread.

EDIT:
Another solution is to download and use the correct modelfile. SOmehow I managed to download a TF2 model but used a previously downloaded TF1 file :-S. All of the above is still correct.